# inserting data to a specific location in a file without overwriting in c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am having a file which stores ints in binary format. And I am writing a function in C++ which takes int data and inserts it to a specific position in file.

```
void AddData(int position, int data);
```

- position is the index at which data has to inserted.
- data is the int value to be inserted.

code

```
void AddData(int position, int data)
{

    fstream os;        
    char buff[4096];
    cnt1 = position;
    cnt2+=(data_cnt-cnt1); // data_cnt is global var to cout the no. of data items 

    os.open("edata.dat", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary );

    os.seekg(0);                    // start from beg
    os.seekg(cnt1*sizeof(int));     // move to position at which data has to be inserted
    os.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff), cnt2*sizeof(int)); // read rest of file 
    os.seekg(cnt1*sizeof(int));     // move back to previous position
    cout << os.tellg();
    os.write( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(int) ); //add data
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff), cnt2*sizeof(int)); //write back the read data
    data_cnt++;
}
```

when function is called first time, it shows data item is added twice. And when function is called 2nd time, tellg() shows -1.

can't figure out, whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I can't see what's wrong either but - forgive me for being that straigforward - your coding style doesn't help !!

There are a lot of things which are wrong in my opinion, in your example :

1. you use a global variable to count the number of items.
2. you assume there won't be more than 4096 bytes in the remainder part
3. your reinterpret_cast is completely unnecessary  (writing 'buff' is the same as writing '&buff[0]' and gives you a char* directly)
4. you don't do any  check whatsoever (is position beyond the end of the file for example
   ?)

Honestly even if you make this code work, every person who has to maintain it will really hate you. (I'm sorry to sound mean but I had to maintain loads of such code in the past and that's a nighmare if something, somewhere suddenly doesn't work because you switched to a 64bit os ;) )

Enough lecturing, time for suggestions :

Why not, simply, do the following :

- copy the source file from the begining to 'position' (and check position is in the boundaries of the file !) to a temp file.
- write your int to your temp file
- copy the source file (from position+1 to eof), to temp file (from position + 2)
- erase the edata.dat, rename temp to edata.dat

It's much easier, safer, cleaner and probably as fast . Most importantly : if something wrong happens before the end, you still have your edata.dat in a stable, uncorrupted state.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, cnt2 is meant to represent the number of ints *after* the int being inserted, right?

In which case it should be `cnt2 = data_cnt-cnt1`, not `cnt2 += data_cnt-cnt1`.  You should probably make those local variables, as they don't need to store anything between calls.

The first time you call the function, you're probably getting cnt2 having the correct value by coincidence.  On the second call, it's being set to double the correct value (because you're incrementing), so the read is failing, and the stream is going into an error state.

I'm not sure why the data might be added twice though.  Perhaps if you fix the cnt2 bug, it might just start working.